# i want to use onblur to validate alpha and hyphen for textbox in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onblur

I want to use javascript to validate using onblur if the user is inputting only alpha values and hyphen in the textbox.

```
*First Name: <input type="text" name="fn" onblur="alphahyphen()"/> <br /> 

*Family Name: <input type="text" name="sn" onblur="alphahyphen()"/><br />

function alphahyphen(){ 
    var letters = /^[a-z A-Z\-]+$/;

    if(task3.fn.value.match(letters)){ 
        return;
    }else{
        alert("Enter alpha");
    }
}
```

I dont want it to show an error message when the field is left empty as i am using an onsubmit for that.

Any help?

Comment: var letters = /^[a-z A-Z\-]+$/;

Comment: @jeff, you don't need to escape `-` if it is the first or last character in the class.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it doesn't hurt to put it in and is there in case you decide to append other characters. :-)